# How to get email from textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
EmailSender email = new EmailSender { 
                                     EmailAdresNaar = "HERE", 
                                     Onderwerp = "Test email", 
                                     Bericht = "<b>Dit is een test</b>"
                                               + "<i>cursief kan ook.</i>." 
                                    };
email.SendEmail();
```

How do i put a string where HERE stands, with a string dat someone put into this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    Email
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Klant.email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Klant.email)
    <input type="submit" value="Verstuur" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: where do you send your email? In your controller? You should have the text entered by the user in your model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:
in view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyMethod", "MyController"))
{
    <div class="editor-label">
    Email
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Klant.email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Klant.email)
    <input type="submit" value="Verstuur" /> 
</div>
}
```

in controller

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(ModelName model)
{
  EmailSender email = 
      new EmailSender { 
                      EmailAdresNaar = model.Klant.email,  
                      Onderwerp = "Test email",  
                      Bericht = "<b>Dit is een test</b> <i>cursief kan ook.</i>."
                    };
  email.SendEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult methodName(Class model)
{
    EmailSender email = new EmailSender { 
                                         EmailAdresNaar = model.Klant.email,  
                                         Onderwerp = "Test email",  
                                         Bericht = "<b>Dit is een test</b>"
                                                   + "<i>cursief kan ook.</i>."
                                        };
    email.SendEmail();
}
```

And your view should be:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("methodName"))
{
<div class="editor-label">
    Email
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Klant.email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Klant.email)
    <input type="submit" value="Verstuur" /> 
</div>
}
```

Maybe read up on the basics of MVC?